# Unwanted white semi transparent overlay on website

Tags: css, wordpress, overlay

I'm setting up an affiliate e-commerce website with WordPress and yesterday an unwanted white semi transparent overlay appeared on it and I have no idea how to remove it. I searched on Google but didn't find a proper answer. It appears on loading and basically disappears after 30 seconds or so.

Please note that I'm pretty new to all of this.

Website is [www.mystupidgift.com](http://www.mystupidgift.com)

Answer (score 0):

Usually when these issues come up, it's best to try and click the "X" to stop the page from loading while the "thing does the thing you want to fix". So while the page has the "overlay", stop the page loading, and then you can open up Dev Tools (F12 in Chrome) and proceed to scroll down through the elements.

For something like this, it's a bit more difficult, because you're generally looking for a full screen element, *but not always*. You can just hit "delete" on them one by one until the undesired thing goes away, (I find this easier to work from the bottom up, since those elements have a higher z-index by default and show up on top of earlier elements).

So I started to do that when I realized that it's **not** actually an overlay, but actually your content is being set to a **lower transparency** (which provides a similar effect, letting the white background of the body bleed through)

Your theme's [`page-in-out.min.css`](http://www.mystupidgift.com/wp-content/themes/shopkeeper/css/misc/page-in-out.min.css?ver=2.9.14) file sets your site's container (`#st-container`) to an opacity of `.2`. This is the effect you want to remedy. It goes away when your website is fully loaded and the `.fade-in` class is added to the `#st-container` which sets the opacity to `1`. I'm not sure which JavaScript file does that, because I didn't look and don't think it's necessary to know.

I'm not familiar with the theme you've chosen, but there very well may be a setting in there like "fade website out until it's loaded", "page in/out", or something to that effect. If you don't want to mess with that, there is no setting, or you can't find it - you *can* just add some [more specific CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to that element to make it always fully opaque, regardless of the `.fade-in` class.

To do that, you can just go to **Appearance > Customize** and open up the **Additional CSS** tab. In there, you can just paste something like:

```css
#st-container.st-container { opacity: 1; }
```

Here's a quick screengrab of the dev tools process that led me to that. While this isn't a  specific answer in general, it's more of a *process* answer, and hopefully you can make use of that process (stop loading, open dev tools, manually dig through elements and look at the CSS and computed styles, delete elements if needed with the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key, etc.) next time something like this comes up!

[image: Image of dev tools showing the opacity]

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for explaining the whole process so I can find answers myself in the future (or at least, try to! lol).